# Why do I keep getting an error on converting a generic list to the same list type?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I am running into this error

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'HWC.DataAccess.FAREmailList' HWC.DataAccess

I am not understanding this error because its the same list type

here is the method that I am using

```
public void PrepareToSendEmailFromFAR(int id)
{
    HWC = new HWCEntities();

    FileAReport far = HWC.FileAReports.Where(w => w.FileAReportID == id).FirstOrDefault();

    List<FAREmailList> emailList = null;



    if(far.DistrictID != 0)
    {
        emailList = new List<FAREmailList>();
        var query = from dcx in HWC.DistrictContactXREFs
                    where
                      dcx.DistrictID == far.DistrictID
                    select new
                    {
                        dcx.ContactID,
                        dcx.Contact.ContactEmail,
                        dcx.Contact.ContactName
                    };

        foreach(var a in query)
        {
            emailList.Add(new FAREmailList
            {
                ContactName = a.ContactName,
                EmailAddress = a.ContactEmail
            });
        }

        SendEmailFromFAR(emailList);
    }

    if(far.DistrictID == 0)
    {
        emailList = new List<FAREmailList>();
        var query = from dcx in HWC.DistrictContactXREFs
                    join d in HWC.Districts on dcx.DistrictID equals d.DistrictID into d_join
                    from d in d_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join sp in HWC.StateProvinces on new { StateProvinceID = d.StateID } equals new { StateProvinceID = sp.StateProvinceID }
                    where
                      d.StateID == far.StateCountyID
                    select new
                    {
                        dcx.ContactID,
                        dcx.Contact.ContactEmail,
                        dcx.Contact.ContactName
                    };

        foreach (var a in query)
        {
            emailList.Add(new FAREmailList
            {
                ContactName = a.ContactName,
                EmailAddress = a.ContactEmail
            });
        }
        SendEmailFromFAR(emailList);
    }
}
```

and here is the method thats receiving the emailList

```
public void SendEmailFromFAR(FAREmailList el)
{

}
```

the data class is

```
public class FAREmailList
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

the error is being thrown at

> SendEmailFromFAR(emailList);

I am not seeing what the issue is, is it because this is all in the same class file?

Comment: `FAREmailList` does not inherit from `List`.  I'm pretty sure you meant to have `SendEmailFromFAR(List<FAREmailList> el)` instead.  Also maybe don't name something that clearly isn't a list `FAREmailList`.

Comment: Your method expetcs a single instance of `FAREmailList`, but you provide a `List<FAREmailList >`.

Comment: `FAREmailList` should probably be named `FAREmail`. This is confusing.

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made the necessary adjustment and it worked.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, its only a typo because you said so, that doesn't necessarily make it so

Comment: You can create the List in one statement. You don't need the anonymous type at all. `emailList = (from ... select new FAREmail { dcx.Contact.ContactEmail, dcx.Contact.ContactName }).ToList()`

Answer (score 3):

The error makes sense to me. `emailList` is of type `List<FAREmailList>` and `SendEmailFromFAR` takes a `FAREmailList` as input.